# Custom 404 page not working (Blogger)

Tags: blogger, html

So I wanted to make a custom 404 page on my [Blog](https://webapps-software.blogspot.com/). I went in `Settings > Errors and redirects > Custom 404` And pasted this Markup:

`<h1 style="height: 0px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Roboto;">Uh-Oh</span></h1><div><span style="font-family: Roboto;"><br /></span></div><h3 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Roboto; font-weight: normal;">Maybe <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank">This</a> is what you're looking for.</span></h3>`
[image]
Although I didn't get a custom 404. I still get ["There's nothing here."](https://webapps-software.blogspot.com/bleh)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [@cyballruiz](https://support.google.com/profile/2377296) at [Google Help](https://support.google.com) helped me with the answer to this:

> The theme you are using Soho Neon, have disabled the custom 404 field. It only show the basic/standar message 'there's nothing here'. What you could do is to edit your HTML theme and edit the following line of code: `<b:eval expr='data:view.isSearch ? data:messages.noResultsFound : data:messages.theresNothingHere'/>`

To solve this problem:

1. Navigate to `Theme` > `My theme` > `Edit HTML` on the blogger dashboard.
2. Search for `<b:eval expr='data:view.isSearch ? data:messages.noResultsFound : data:messages.theresNothingHere'/>` (Using Ctrl+F while text cursor is active)
3. Replace it with the code for your 404 page, in my case, which would be

```
<h1 style="height: 0px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Roboto;">Uh-Oh</span></h1><div><span style="font-family: Roboto;"><br /></span></div><h3 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Roboto; font-weight: normal;">Maybe <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank">This</a> is what you're looking for.</span></h3>
```

[[link to the og post](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/145849978?hl=en)]